# No route to host found - OpenStack

Tags: ssh, openstack

I'm using a public cloud for Openstack and created an instance of ubuntu. When I tried to ssh (or) ping to the IP address available there, it says "No route to host found" and "Host Unreachable". How to fix it?

Comment: Login to instance via horizon and check wether ip address is up by `ifconfig`. If yes assign a floating IP and try ping.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a DNS record was automatically created when starting VM in your Openstack cloud? You could check this via **dig** command.

Answer (score 0):

By default all OpenStack environments have security group rules which block all inbound packets to guests. If you want to be able to ssh / ping your created guests you should run the following.

```
openstack security group rule create --proto icmp --dst-port 0 default
openstack security group rule create --proto tcp --dst-port 22 default
```

^^^ The above part is from [this link](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/networking.html)

If you get an error for the network name then you can use the id of each of your networks.